# Android App Counter

Tags: android, counter, auto-increment

I have created a Purchase Order android app which has multiple users for all our employees. At the moment the app is used as a duplicate of a paper system so the employees have to manually type the purchase order number.

I am looking for a way so we can make a counter that will increase every time a user starts a new order but I want to make sure that the same number is not used by multiple users.

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: what effort you have put so far to achieve this ?

Comment: try synchronizing integer or try using atomic integer to generate the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `SharedPreferences` to implement this. It will give you a new auto incremented number every time.

```
public int getAutoIncrementedNumber() {
    int count = 0;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    int defaultValue = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("count_key", count);
    ++defaultValue;
    getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("count_key", defaultValue).commit();
    return getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("count_key", count);
}
```

Comment: Will this allow for user on different devices to work off the same increment.

For example User A logs in on Device A and is given number 1. When User B logs in on Device B i need them get number 2.

Comment: No. It doesn't  allow for user on different devices to work off the same increment.

Comment: Ok, do you know what I would need to do to allow that?

Comment: Sorry. You can't do it without using server.